json2html not outputting as described, want to remove generated outer table
I'm using json2html (python) and the outputs are not matching what is shown at the website.
https://pypi.org/project/json2html/
Basically, using the site example:
from json2html import *

input = {
    "sample": [{
        "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3
    }, {
        "a": 5, "b": 6, "c": 7
    }]}

json2html.convert(json=input)

Shows the output on the website as a table of 2 rows.

However, the html created and embedded on the same page now outputs this (and is also what the code now says it is doing), just ignore the table formatting that is just my css styling:

If I remove the 'sample' element name it produces two separate tables and clubbing True/False just makes it worse.
Can anyone let me know how to get it to show the version the website describes it as the left-sided name is pretty ugly and redundant. Thanks.

To achieve that, remove the sample and pass a list of two rows like this:
from json2html import *

inp = [
    {
        "a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3  # row 1
    },
    {
        "a": 5, "b": 6, "c": 7  # row 2
    }
]
json2html.convert(json=inp)

Result:


Thanks, but I tried that and all I get from this is always two separate tables. Whether I use clubbing True or False

You have passed a dictionary. You should pass a list like what I have shown.

I literally pasted your code sample. What I actually get using this is two list items and the table is transposed, i.e. the a/b/c headers are actually the first columns data
a1b2c3a5b6c7
That is weird. This is the output I get from that: <table border="1"><thead><tr><th>a</th><th>b</th><th>c</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td></tr><tr><td>5</td><td>6</td><td>7</td></tr></tbody></table> Which is clearly a correct table

I'm using v1.3.0 from the pypi site

I'm using the same version. and the table image is directly from that code.

Erm, I really sorry :(
Your answer was correct, it was because of the dictionary name needing removing, but I tried so many things with clubbing I got lost in the code. I added this line in trying to convert the column headers into something nice then forgot about it, which screwed with the data.
column_headers = [x.title().replace('_',' ') for x in column_headers]
